# HBase 2.0.0: Region in Transision Hole in Region Chain

Tags: hbase

I run HBase `2.0.0.3.0.2.0-50` and have one Region in trainsition. This leads to my tables become unaccessable. How to bring this Region back?

Checking the hbase via `hbase hbck` results in

```
    ERROR: Region { 
        meta => SYSTEM.STATS,,154...49.0ca06...916., 
        hdfs => wasb://....blob.core.windows.net/hbase/data/default/
           SYSTEM.STATS/0ca06...916, 
        deployed => , 
        replicaId => 0 
    } not deployed on any region server.
```

In addition I see an error there regarding a `hole in the Region chain`:

```
ERROR: There is a hole in the region chain between 
\x01...\x00 and \x02...\x00.  
You need to create a new .regioninfo and region dir in hdfs to plug the hole.
```

Some answers suggests to use the `-fix` Switch of `hbase hbck`. Unfortunately this isn't supported any more as `hbase hbck -fix` gracefully tells me:

```
NOTE: Following options are NOT supported as of HBase version 2.0+.

  UNSUPPORTED Metadata Repair options: (expert features, use with caution!)
   -fix              Try to fix region assignments.  This is for backwards compatiblity
 ...
```

http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#HBCK2 Then told me to use `hbck2`instead. After compiling it and running (`HBASE_CLASSPATH_PREFIX=~/hbase-hbck2.jar hbase org.apache.hbase.HBCK2`) I tried to re-assign the Region using `assigns` option with the encoded region-name (`0ca06...916`)

Funny result:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
Requires 2.0.3 at least.
```

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that there was a misconfiguration in HBase: The HBase logs contained another error:

```
hbase-hbase-regionserver-....log 2019-... ERROR [RS_LOG_REPLAY_OPS-regionserver/...] wal.WALSplitter: 
Got while writing log entry to log java.io.IOException: 
cannot get log writerat 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.FSHLogProvider.createWriter(FSHLogProvider.java:96) 
Caused by: 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CommonFSUtils$StreamLacksCapabilityException: hflush {code}
```

Setting `hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce` to `false` in `hbase-site.xml` and restarting all Region Servers / Services resolved the issue.